# Using selfmade Navigation class with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, navigation

I just started using CodeIgniter, now I have included my own classes in the libraries file of CI and I want to use them for my navigation.

the problem is that I don't know where to call this class and how to use it with CI standards.. i've been searching all night for this without luck... could someone give me the correct answer?

in a normal way I would do something like this to call the navigation class and to use it.

```
    $menu = new Navigation("navigation");
    $menu_items = array("home", "about");

    foreach($menu_items as $items) { 
       $items = new NavigationItem();
       $items->setMenuItem($item);
       $menu->addChild($items);
    }
echo $menu->display();
```

the code I currently use is:

```
        $construct = array(
        'name' => 'nav'
    );

    $menu_items = array("home", "about");

    $men = $this->load->library('Navigation', $construct);
    foreach($menu_items as $item) {
        $item = $this->load->library('NavigationItem');
        $this->navigationitem->setMenuItem($item);
        $this->navigation->addChild($item);
    }

    $this->navigation->display();
```

Comment: Since when there are any standards in CI regarding MVC. If you are talking about "CI-style" then it would be to load/manipulate (preferably, using CI's loader monstrosity) that class instance withing the "controller" and then pass the result of `display()` to what they call "view".

Comment: You really want to reassign $item in foreach as it is getting assigned again, and you are loosing last object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in the "Using your class" section on the user guide:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

```
   $construct = array(
    'name' => 'nav'
);

$menu_items = array("home", "about");

$men = $this->load->library('Navigation', $construct);
foreach($menu_items as $menu) {
    $this->load->library('NavigationItem');
    $this->navigationitem->setMenuItem($menu);
    $this->navigation->addChild($this->navigationitem);
}

$this->navigation->display();
```

Comment: I did this already.. See my new code in my start post but it doesn't work it says the addChild part must be an instance of navigationitem, null given in ...

Comment: perhaps try the code in my (edited) answer? I'd have to take a look at the class to help more

Comment: it works kinda.. but the problem is that I get 2 times about. and no index besides that it now echoes in my controller and I don;t think that is the purpose of MvC.. :(